# Microsoft Word automatically password-protecting documents

Tags: microsoft-word, passwords, xml

I have a very weird issue I'm working on. We have some Microsoft Word documents that will randomly apply a password to it when saved. It doesn't happen all the time and I can't pinpoint if there's a specific reason why it happens, but it's becoming a big issue for a client of ours.

I did notice one strange thing. When opening the document (without the password lock) and using Microsoft Word's document inspector tool, the inspector finds custom xml. When this custom XML is removed and then the document is saved and closed, when it's re-opened, the password is applied. Perhaps it has something to do with the custom xml in the documents? Is there any way to view any custom xml in a Microsoft Word document (.doc)??

Comment: Download the Content Control Toolkit and you should be able to view the custom XML.  http://dbe.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a version of this for .doc files or does it just handle .docx? The files we're working with are .doc.

Comment: Is the problem repeatable with .docx?

Comment: I don't think so. When I convert to a docx, it doesn't really seem to happen. The only problem is that the documents are in a sharepoint site and we can't really just convert them to docx as we'll lose version history and such.

Comment: bump for others to see